# wordpress - woocommerce says: Registered Users are able to view pricing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When a non-registered user attempts to see the price of a product, it says

> Registered Users are able to view pricing.

I'm not sure if this is something to do with the WooCommerce settings or PHP code.

Is there away I can remove this, so the users don't have to register to see the prices.

Comment: You forgot to add the question ^^

Comment: @JimL Oops, I added it :P

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/

Comment: Please, could you be more explicit: are you using other woocommerce plugins? have you changed some things in WooCommerce?

Comment: @JimL Kindly, but this is the doc of a woocommerce commercial add-on, is not part of basic woocommerce...

Comment: There is no default functionality like this in woocommerce. There must be a because of another plugin or script inside the functions.php.